# My Servlet Application could not load my DemoServlet class

Tags: java, servlets

I created my first servlet

Folder PATH listing

Volume serial number is 00000200 FC75:CC21

C:.
│   index.html.xml
│
└───WEB-INF
    │   web.xml
    │   web2.xml
    │
    ├───classes
    │       DemoServlet.class
    │       DemoServlet.java
    │
    └───lib

now The web.xml file

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>D</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>DemoServlet<servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>D<servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and it is not working as expected

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
    pw.println("<html><body>");
    pw.println("<h1> Welcome to Servlets</h1>");
    pw.println("</body></html>");
    pw.close();
}
}
```

and then
http://localhost:8080/helloWorld/welcome

it is not working

But I copied the web.xml from internet

web.xml(Correct)

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>DemoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and it is working fine as expected.

I checked it many times.But I cannot the error or difference in my web.xml and copied web.xml file?

You can reproduce this error
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1492raP2paEQF8qlKKRf4VN5bS2W3iCHL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not close your `servlet-class` elements correctly.  These should look like:

```
<servlet-class>DemoServlet</servlet-class>
```